# PHP string comparison for strpos strcmp

Tags: php, security, comparison, difference

I'm using PHP 7.0 and I want to do only string comparison. PHP has strpos strcmp function to do that but I don't know which function will be fast and safe to do string comparison. I have to compare a lot of string and I want to know which function would bring faster result.

In my test, strpos doesn't return NULL for array string comparison but strcmp does. In PHP 7 I tested, but I may use other PHP version for hosting and this problem will be sensitive. Is okay to use if (strpos($x, $y)) to use string comparison?

Comment: If you're just trying to find out if they're the same just do:
if($a == $b) { //do something }

Comment: AA.... I'm just think that... thank for ansering!!! Is if (strpos($x, $y)) safe to compare?

Comment: Because I might not fully comprehend what want to do with it, I suggest you read the documentation. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 2):

strpos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string

strcmp — Binary safe string comparison

If the string is a string of text like you would get from user input or anything that is not binary then strcmp seems overkill.
I would use Difster's suggestion; It read cleaner then if (strcmp($a,$b))

mixed strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )

This is the method signature for strpos will the return a truthy value if $b is in $a. So i would not use it to compare if two string are equal only if you want to see if a string is inside another or want to know where the string is at inside the other.